# Removing ehcache on any table update

Tags: mysql, caching, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I am using ehcache which is caching item table information

```
Ex: Item table 
Item_id : 101 
Part_no: PX_1001
Price: 10
```

Note : 
In first database call it will cache the item info in cache but if i am trying to update price of this item in database then price is not reflecting in cache.
 How we can archive this if someone update the row in DB which is already in cache should update the same time in cache or get updated value from data base ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical invalidation problem. If it is your application performing the update, make sure it updates the cache entry as well.

If your database is updated externally to your application, you will need to come up with a scheme so that you can either invalidate or update cache entries.

Another path, which depends on your business requirements, is to set an expiry settings (time-to-live or TTL in this case) on cache entries so that you still benefit from caching but eventually pull the updated value in the cache because the previous mapping will have expired.